# Regex XML check if value is pressent using java

Tags: java, regex

I have XML document and like to find the value 37.42.

Numrisk value may vary.

XML tag is:

```
<Value UOM="CubicMeter">37.42</Value>
```

My best shot is

```
/^ ((<Value UOM="CubicMeter">)(\d+ (\.\d*)(</Value>) )
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? Edit your question and show us your attempts please

Comment: /^ ((<Value UOM="CubicMeter">)(\d+ (\.\d*)(</Value>) ) my best shot :-)

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<Value UOM="CubicMeter">(\d+(?:.\d+)?)
```

but you'd better use a parser instead

Comment: Thanks for the awesome suggestions. Have checked into XML parser worked like charm.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @MagnusL you're welcome!